# PHP no me deja actualizar un formulaio, tengo un checkbox, ¿lo estoy haciendo bien?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

estoy tratando de actualizar unos datos que tengo en un formulario y mostrar como seleccionados los checkbox que tengo en él, a diferencia de las respuestas que he encontrado no estoy utlizando AJAX y esta es la manera que estoy implementando, mis valores que estoy primero tomando son estos, estos son las casillas de mis filas en la BD con el nombre del row y algunas variables para hacer esa conversión de string a valor, creo.....

```
$a = $e_subscription_row['tipo_suscripcion'];
$b = explode(", ", $a);
```

Después lo que intenté pues fue guardar los nombres que tengo en el formulario a unas variables "actualizadoras" que toman en cuenta los cambios y se incluyen en el update de SQL. Muestro este contexto:

```
if(isset($_POST['update_subscriber'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $u_member_group = $_POST['member_group'];
    $u_member_name = $_POST['member_name'];
    $u_subscription = $_POST['subscription'];
    $u_subscription_type = $_POST['tipo'];
    $d = implode(", ", $u_subscription_type);

    $u_subscription_query = "UPDATE plenitud_suscripciones
                             SET grupo = '$u_member_group',
                             miembro = '$u_member_name',
                             suscripcion = '$u_subscription',
                             tipo_suscripcion = '$d'
                             WHERE id = '$id'";

    $u_subscription_result = mysqli_query($conn, $u_subscription_query);
}
```

Esta es la parte del formulario de los checbkox que intento mostrar como seleccionados siempre y cuando sean seleccionados.

```
    <form action="editar_suscripcion.php?=<?php echo "{$_GET['id']}"?>" method="POST">
        <div class="checkboxes">
            <label for="grupal">Grupo</label> <input class="text-input" type="checkbox" value="grupal" name="tipo[ ]" value="<?php echo "{$e_subscription_type}"?>"
            <?php if(in_array("grupal", $b)); { echo "checked"; } ?>>
            <label for="distrito">Distrito</label> <input class="text-input" type="checkbox" value="distrito" name="tipo[ ]" value="<?php echo "{$e_subscription_type}"?>"
            <?php if(in_array("distrito", $b)); { echo "checked"; } ?>>
        </div>
        <input class="save-btn" type="submit" name="update_subscriber" value="Guardar">
    </form>
```

Este es el error que recibo:

Notice: Undefined index: id in /opt/lampp/htdocs/plenitud/includes/editar_suscripcion.php on line 20

Por último este viene siendo la primera parte donde están las filas de la BD y el nombre del row

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $e_subscription_query = "SELECT * FROM plenitud_suscripciones WHERE id = '$id'";
    $e_subscription_result = mysqli_query($conn, $e_subscription_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($e_subscription_result) == 1) {
        $e_subscription_row = mysqli_fetch_array($e_subscription_result);
        $e_member_group = $e_subscription_row['grupo'];
        $e_member_name = $e_subscription_row['miembro'];
        $e_subscription = $e_subscription_row['suscripcion'];
        $a = $e_subscription_row['tipo_suscripcion'];
        $b = explode(", ", $a);
    }
}
```

Por cierto la línea 20 al cuál se refiere el error es esta, es la que se encuentra DEBAJO de: `if(isset($_POST['update_subscriber']))`

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los parámetros GET se escriben de la siguiente forma:

> ruta.php?parametro1=valor1&parametro2=valor2...

En tu ruta te faltó agregar el parametro "id" después del **.php**, corrigiendo quedaría así:

```
<form action="editar_suscripcion.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: ah que bien, si puede editar pero creo que no incluí bien mi array en las variables encargadas de actualizar la base de datos... ya que me arroja un "Notice" y un "Warning", crees que deba de hacer otra entrada?

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje te muestra?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: tipo in /opt/lampp/htdocs/plenitud/includes/editar_suscripcion.php on line 24  ```$u_subscription_type = $_POST['tipo'];```


Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/plenitud/includes/editar_suscripcion.php on line 25  ```$d = implode(", ", $u_subscription_type);```

Comment: en tu input el `name="tipo[ ]"` tiene un espacio entre los corchetes, quizás por eso no reconoce el indice "tipo" en tu variable $_POST, prueba quintando ese espacio:
`name="tipo[]"`

Comment: Lo que pasa que cuando agrego un registro y luego quiero editar, los checkbox aparecen seleccionados sin yo haberlos seleccionados, ese error surge cuando de-selecciono los checkbox y presiono el "submit"